# Multiple objects comparison using javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I had a array of objects (multiple objects) and want to compare them with dynamically added objects.

currently my code looks like

```
public compare(row) {
    for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
      var a = row[i];
      console.log(a, 'first array !!!!!!!');

      var b = row[i + 1];
      console.log(b, 'Second array !!!!!!!');

      if (a != undefined && b != undefined) {
        return JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b);
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }

    }
  }
```

but I'm able to compare only first two records only . is there a way to compare the objects dynamically using javascript.
Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

Your loop always returns at the end of the first loop. You only want to return false inside the loop if you find a mismatch, otherwise let the loop continue. If it doesn't find any mismatches, then you know your objects match, and you can return true.

```js
public compare(row) {
  for (var i = 0; i < row.length - 1; i++) {
    var a = row[i];
    var b = row[i + 1];
    if (!a || !b) {
      continue;
    }

    if (JSON.stringify(a) !== JSON.stringify(b)) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

I've also set the loop to only continue while `i < row.length - 1`, since there is no element at `row[row.length]`.

DEMO

```js
var equal = [
 { a: 1 },
 undefined,
 { a: 1 },
 { a: 1 }
];

var notEqual = [
 { a: 1 },
 undefined,
 { a: 1 },
 { a: 1 },
 { a: 2 }
];

function compare(row) {
  for (var i = 0; i < row.length - 1; i++) {
    var a = row[i];
    var b = row[i + 1];

    if (!a || !b) {
      continue;
    }
    
    if (JSON.stringify(a) !== JSON.stringify(b)) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

console.log('should be true: ', compare(equal));
console.log('should be false: ', compare(notEqual));
```